# How to return False when file exists with FIleSensor

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to reverse `FileSensor()`: that is, with

```
sensor=FileSensor(filepath='test.txt', task_id='dummy_file_test')
```

It will return True if the file exists. But, how can it return False when the file exists and True when it does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a PythonSensor that checks for the existence of a file with the logic that you want.

```
def my_sensor_func(some_path):
    return not os.exists(some_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by creating your own function:

```
SF = lambda **kwargs: not FileSensor(**kwargs)
sensor=SF(filepath='test.txt', task_id='dummy_file_test')
```